# Android Java - how to find out visible text on a TextView that is on the ScrollView

Tags: java, android, textview, scrollview

well, I v'e got a ScrollView and a TextView on this where I load different Stings - it could be in one screen or you have to scroll this TextView 50 screens down.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AllPr"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"  >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alltextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="TextView" />


    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Text I set is through Spannable
My question - is there any way to find out what text is visible to user Right now and if it is - can I find which text is set as **bold text** because what I need from there are headers

Comment: Don't you think your question is incomplete ? You need to complete and brief your question more.

Comment: What exactly didn't I write? I just need a way to get an onscreen area of text that is in TextView that is in ScrollView - that's it. If it's possible to find what part of text is bold - it would be great